# How to understand creating leaf tensors in PyTorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, documentation

From PyTorch [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html):

```
b = torch.rand(10, requires_grad=True).cuda()
b.is_leaf
False
# b was created by the operation that cast a cpu Tensor into a cuda Tensor

e = torch.rand(10).cuda().requires_grad_()
e.is_leaf
True
# e requires gradients and has no operations creating it

f = torch.rand(10, requires_grad=True, device="cuda")
f.is_leaf
True
# f requires grad, has no operation creating it
```

But why are `e` and `f` leaf Tensors, when they both were also cast from a CPU Tensor, into a Cuda Tensor (an operation)?

Is it because Tensor `e` was cast into Cuda *before* the in-place operation `requires_grad_()`?

And because `f` was cast by assignment `device="cuda"` rather than by method `.cuda()`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When a tensor is first created, it becomes a leaf node.

Basically, all inputs and weights of a neural network are leaf nodes of the computational graph.

When *any* operation is performed on a tensor, it is not a leaf node anymore.

```
b = torch.rand(10, requires_grad=True) # create a leaf node
b.is_leaf # True
b = b.cuda() # perform a casting operation
b.is_leaf # False
```

`requires_grad_()` is not an operation in the same way as `cuda()` or others are.
It creates a new tensor, because tensor which requires gradient (trainable weight) cannot depend on anything else.

```
e = torch.rand(10) # create a leaf node
e.is_leaf # True
e = e.cuda() # perform a casting operation
e.is_leaf # False
e = e.requires_grad_() # this creates a NEW tensor
e.is_leaf # True
```

Also, `detach()` operation creates a new tensor which does not require gradient:

```
b = torch.rand(10, requires_grad=True)
b.is_leaf # True
b = b.detach()
b.is_leaf # True
```

In the last example we create a new tensor which is already on a cuda device.
We do not need any operation to cast it.

```
f = torch.rand(10, requires_grad=True, device="cuda") # create a leaf node on cuda
```

Comment: Since `b = b.cuda() # perform a casting operation` makes `b` point to a new object why it is not a leaf anymore? Is the previous leaf remembered (since it was destroyed during variable declaration)?

Comment: @adosar yes, torch.autograd remembers sequence of operations. But if you do the same within `with torch.no_grad():` context, then you will be creating leaf nodes every time, because autograd will be disabled.