# ValueError: Can't optimize a non-leaf Tensor,but requires_grad is true

Tags: python, optimization, pytorch

I am trying to optimize self.parameters() with torch.optim.adam.Here is the original code:

```
    def learning_rate_adjust(self, args):
      self.learning_rate *= 0.8
      self.train_op = torch.optim.Adam(self.parameters(), lr=self.learning_rate, weight_decay=args.l2_reg)
```

but when I run this code,here is the bug:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "main.py", line 37, in <module>
      train(args, loader, train_set_length, test_seq, item_attr_set, [], [])
   File "E:\ACAM\0324ACAM-model-master\ACAM-model\code\train.py", line 62, in train
      net.learning_rate_adjust(args)
   File "E:\ACAM\0324ACAM-model-master\ACAM-model\code\model.py", line 160, in learning_rate_adjust
      self.train_op = torch.optim.Adam(self.parameters(), lr=self.learning_rate, weight_decay=args.l2_reg)
   File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\bio\lib\site-packages\torch\optim\adam.py", line 42, in __init__
      super(Adam, self).__init__(params, defaults)
   File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\bio\lib\site-packages\torch\optim\optimizer.py", line 51, in __init__
      self.add_param_group(param_group)
   File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\bio\lib\site-packages\torch\optim\optimizer.py", line 202, in 
      add_param_group
      raise ValueError("can't optimize a non-leaf Tensor")
ValueError: can't optimize a non-leaf Tensor
```

so I try to see the list of self.parameters(),and i found list(self.parameters())[9] is a a non-leaf Tensor,then like some similar others' questions,i print the code like:

```
print('9',list(self.parameters())[9].requires_grad)
>>>true
print('9',list(self.parameters())[9].is_leaf)
>>>false
```

so i dont know how to change my code,please help me.T T

Comment: Hello, can you add some code snippet to display how the `self` object is created ? WIthout that, it's hard to point the error out. Also, here is a useful thread for you to read : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65301875/how-to-understand-creating-leaf-tensors-in-pytorch

Comment: thank you first！I read this link but still cant understand how to modify,the other code  is in the comments below.

Answer (score 0):

here is code about the model first:

```
class KAAM(torch.nn.Module):
   def __init__(self, args, ent_embed, attr_embed, item_attr_set, loader, use_user_attn=True,use_item_attn=True, use_pretrain=True):
       super(KAAM,self).__init__()
       self.Super_parameter_construct(args, loader, use_user_attn, use_item_attn, use_pretrain)
       self.variable_construct(args, ent_embed, item_attr_set, attr_embed)
       self.optimizer(args)
       for name, p in self.named_parameters():
           if 'set' not in name:
              p.requires_grad = True
```

then about opotimizer:

```
def optimizer(self,args):
    self.loss_func = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    self.learning_rate, l2_reg = args.learning_rate, args.l2_reg
    self.train_op = torch.optim.Adam(self.parameters(), lr=self.learning_rate, weight_decay=l2_reg)
```

when I train,for some k in my epoches,i will adjust learning rate(learning_rate_adjust) which is The problem code I asked first.