# Why is Tensor not a leaf tensor?

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor, autograd

I'm working on a program in which I initialise leaf node tensors (which require gradients) with the same values as existing tensors. As a simple example of such a program, I create 4 tensors as follows:

```py
a = torch.tensor(4, dtype=torch.float32)
b = a.detach().clone().requires_grad_(True)
c = b*b
d = torch.empty_like(c).copy_(c).requires_grad_(True)
print(b.is_leaf) # True
print(d.is_leaf) # False
```

`d` is not a leaf node. If I define `b` as `b = a.detach().clone()` (IE don't call `requires_grad_(True)` for `b`), then both `b` and `d` **are** leaf nodes:

```py
a = torch.tensor(4, dtype=torch.float32)
b = a.detach().clone()
c = b*b
d = torch.empty_like(c).copy_(c).requires_grad_(True)
print(b.is_leaf) # True
print(d.is_leaf) # True
```

Why does the way in which `b` is defined determine whether or not `d` is a leaf node?

Note that if I define `d` as `d = c.detach().clone().requires_grad_(True)` (using `detach.clone` instead of `empty_like.copy_`), then `d` is a leaf node regardless of whether or not I call `requires_grad_(True)` for `b`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar question: [How to understand creating leaf tensors in PyTorch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65301875/how-to-understand-creating-leaf-tensors-in-pytorch)

You could check that out, I think it should be understandable from that.

Also useful documentations:

- https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.requires_grad_.html#torch.Tensor.requires_grad_
- https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/autograd.html
- https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.is_leaf.html

In your first example, you create a tensor:
`a = torch.tensor(4, dtype=torch.float32)` which is by convention, a *leaf*. Your `b` is still a *leaf*, that you created with `requires_grad_(True)`. Then you, perform an operation on this tensor (that has `requires_grad=True`!!!) by `b * b`, making `c` not a leaf tensor anymore.

However in your second example, you do not perform any operations on tensors that have `requires_grad=True`, so your operations are not recorded.
All of these tensors - by convention - are leaf tensors. Last line of your second example, just makes a copy of your `c` tensor (still no operations recorded), and returns a NEW tensor that has `requires_grad=True`. But in this example, this is the first tensor such that it requires gradients, with no operations performed on it, still making it a *leaf* node.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is interesting. But I think your answer seems to contradict the answer from the question you posted, which states "When *any* operation is performed on a tensor, it is not a leaf node anymore". In the second example above, `c` is defined as an operation on `b` (`c = b*b`), so why should `c` still be a leaf node?

Comment: Also, in the first example, `d` is created as a new tensor and just has the value of `c` copied into it - shouldn't `d` be a leaf node, because it is created as a new tensor (with `torch.empty_like`)? Or do gradients propagate through the `copy_` function? (I originally assumed they wouldn't, but I'm starting to think maybe I was wrong about that...)

Comment: In answer to my first question, should the statement be amended to say "When any operation is performed on a tensor **that requires a gradient**, it is not a leaf node anymore, **but operations on leaf nodes that don't require gradients produce leaf nodes**"?

Comment: When you do not use gradients, operations are not recorded, hence there is not any. If this makes any sense. An operation will only count as such, if it is recorded, but in the second example it is not, while in the first it is recorded.
So basically, yes, when you perform operations on tensors with no grads, then none will be recorded -> they are *leaves* by convention.